# Using Select2 in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, jquery-select2

I'm really having difficulty integrating `select2` in ember.

I want to transform this:

```
<input type="hidden" value=user />
```

into a search input with ajax using `select2` and bind the selected result to the `user` attribute in model.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

{{view}} is deprecated in ember 2.0 +

I found [this](https://istefo.github.io/ember-select-2/#/) project that emberfies select2 into a component

```
ember install ember-select-2
```

or [this one](https://github.com/netguru/ember-select-guru)

```
ember install ember-select-guru
```

Edit 1:

There is also a more active nativley built one and you should probably use this one

```
ember install ember-power-select
```

[repo](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select)

Answer (score 1):

You must first give a normal select box and apply select2 after that. 
To create a select box in ember,

```
{{view Ember.Select viewName="select2View"
                contentBinding="optionList"
        optionLabelPath="content.label"
        optionValuePath="content.value"
        prompt=""
        valueBinding="user"}}
```

where "optionsList" is the list to be populated in select. See the example below

> [{"label": "label1", "value":1}, {"label": "label2", "value":2}]

Then if label1 is selected, "user" will have a value 1.

OR

alternatively you can also refer this [Git](http://goo.gl/mrAV41)

Answer (score 0):

I know you're specifically asking for Select2 help, but if the exact library you're using isn't that important, you might want to try the [select widget](http://addepar.github.io/#/ember-widgets/select) by Addepar. It's based off of Select2, so it's very similar. It will provide the search functionality for you and will bind the selected value for you. It's also fairly easy to customize the styling of it.